# Autoincrement Field with prefix and Year/Month data

Tags: php

This is php code i write

```
$sql="select max(substr(form_number,18)) as mx from csr_it_request where substr(form_number,15,2)=month(now()) order by mx";
$rs=CustomQuery($sql);
$data=db_fetch_array($rs);
$str="CSR/RF/IT/";
$str2=date("Y/m/");
$str3=($data["mx"]+1);
$values["form_number"]="$str$str2".str_pad($str3, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

my expected result is when everytime user add the entry to the database, the "form_number" field will automatically generated.

example : 
CSR/RF/IT/2020/01/001,
CSR/RF/IT/2020/01/002,
CSR/RF/IT/2020/01/003,
...

the problem is, with that code, the result is :
CSR/RF/IT/2020/01/001,
CSR/RF/IT/2020/01/001,
CSR/RF/IT/2020/01/001,
...

the serial number in the last section is always the same.

how can i fix it?

Comment: Do you give us $data array values so I make sure code is work for you or not.

Comment: Try `select max(form_number) as mx from csr_it_request order by mx limit 1` and `$values["form_number"] = $data["mx"]; $values["form_number"]++;`